# How can I display a number if it's divisible by two numbers but not a third in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, division, modulo

How can I display a number if it's divisible by two numbers but not a third in java? I'm not sure if I got the last operator right in relation to this part `|| ((a % 4) == 0))` of the code below.

```
int a = 15;

if ((( a % 5) == 0) || ((a % 10) == 0) || ((a % 4) == 0)) {
    System.out.println("Number entered is divisible by 5 and 10 but not 4");
} else {
    System.out.println("ERROR");
}
```

Comment: FYI `a%10==0` implies that `a%5==0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation

Your condition is wrong. Let me explain what your condition means in english. You have written:

```
(( a % 5) == 0) || ((a % 10) == 0) || ((a % 4) == 0)
```

That translates to *`a` is divisible by `5` **or** it is divisible by `10` **or** it is divisible by `4`.*

There are two issues:

1. You combined them with **or** instead **and** (`&&`)
2. You check if its divisible by `4`, not if it is **not** divisible by `4` (`!= 0`)

---

### Solution

The correct condition would be:

```
a % 5 == 0 && a % 10 == 0 && a % 4 != 0
```

---

### Notes

The parenthesis can be dropped due to operator precedence (see the [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)).

Note that `a % 10 == 0` already implies `a % 5 == 0`. So for those specific numbers, you can simplify the condition to just:

```
a % 10 == 0 && a % 4 != 0
```

Answer (score 2):

change `||` to `&&` and `(a % 4) == 0)` to `(a % 4) != 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your if condition correctly use && instead of || as shown below,
Also you can make your code more efficient by not checking a%10==0 condition as this is redundant(Any no divisible by 10 is also divisible by 5)
Try below code. This should work.

```
int a = 15;
if ( (a%5 == 0) && (a%4 != 0)) {
    System.out.println("Number entered is divisible by 5 and 10 but not 4");
} else {
    System.out.println("ERROR");
}
```